# Asp.net sending data from html to controller by AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I just started using .net and I'm trying to send data from a .html file to controller using AJAX. My ajax call:

```
var dataValue = {
            ID: 10,
            Name: 'Test'
        };
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/waitingList/apply",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataValue,
            success: function (result) {
                console.debug(result);
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                console.debug(xhr);
                var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
                if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                    err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
                alert(err);
            }
        });
```

My controller:

```
[Route("waitingList/apply")]
public class WaitingListController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(WaitingList wList)
    {

        return string.Format("Test"); 
    }
}
```

When I run it, my AJAX return an error: "Not Found". I don't know why. My index.html is in the root and the controller in the controller folder of my MVC project. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Move your `[Route("waitingList/apply")]`  to the method (not on the controller)

Comment: Thanks, but still the same problem

Comment: Have you enabled attribute routing? Just try by commenting it out and using `url: "/waitingList/post",`. And if that is still giving you a 404, post the full details of the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller like this.

```
public class WaitingListController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("waitingList/apply")]
    public string Apply(WaitingList wList)
    {
        return string.Format("Test"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Why do I need to change the name of the method to Apply? Sorry i am new

Comment: You do not need to change the method name to `Apply`. If that is what made it work, then clearly you did not set up attribute routing correctly.

Comment: Yes, it should also work without changing the name of the method if Attribute routing is enabled in MVC project. Add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in your `RouteConfig` class and try.